# Passing parameter to alias which is part of a string

Tags: bash, alias

Sorry if this is a silly question.

I have 4 directories in my workspace dir1, dir2, dir3 and dirzz.
I need to setup an alias with one parameter to decide which directory to be called.
For example

```
$ gotodir 1
```

this should take me to dir1

```
$ gotodir z
```

this should take me to dirzz

I tried
`alias gotodir="cd ~/home/user/dir${1}"
alias gotodir='cd ~/home/user/dir$1'`

But both throws error

Could someone help me here
Thanks in advance

Comment: `~` equivalently `/home/user/`...Try `alias gotodir="cd ~/dir${1}"`

Comment: Tried still throws same error.

Comment: then use the function `gotodir() { cd ~/dir${1}; }` Alias ​​probably doesn't support calling with parameter

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [bash man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) in the `alias` section:

> There is no mechanism for using arguments in the replacement text. If arguments are needed, a shell function should be used

So to do what you want just define a function instead:

```
gotodir() { cd ~/dir"$1"; }
```

Then just call it as:

```
gotodir 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function **inside** the alias:

```
 alias gotodir='function _gtdir() { cd ~/dir${1} ; } ; _gtdir '
```

Comment: But then things like `whatever || gotodir 1` won't work properly.

Comment: Here I assumed the purpose of aliases is generally not to be used inside scripts, but rather as an customized command entered manually, which is likely the case in the original question context. 
Nevertheless, I'd like to know what exactly could work not properly? Does your comment relate to interacitve or scirpt use? Do you imply the (unset) expand_aliases shell option in there?

Comment: alias expansion is just replacement of text with other text before undergoing another round of syntax parsing (a very ugly hack copied from csh which didn't have functions), so the `whatever || gotodir 1` is going to become `whatever || function _gtdir() { cd ~/dir${1} ; } ; _gtdir`, so the `||` will only apply to the function definition, and the `_gtdir` function will be called regardless of whether `whatever` succeeded or not.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Good point indeed. Hopefully `||` case is just beyond of original question use case

Answer (score 1):

You say “`gotodir z` should take me to dirzz” 
As far as I can see, none of the answers posted so far will do that. 
But we need to change only one character from [kaylum’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/561355/80216#561358):

```
gotodir() {
        cd ~/dir"$1"*
}
```

Note the addition of the `*` glob character. 
This way, `gotodir z` will take you to the first thing in your home directory
whose name ***begins*** with `dirz` (if any, and if it is a directory).

Tested in bash. 
I don’t know whether this will work in all shells.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to setup the CDPATH variable. It contains a comma separated list of directories `cd` examines when switching to a relative directory. If the directory names are too long, use symbolic links.